# PL/SQL функция, которую я не могу понять

Tags: sql, функции, plsql

```
DECLARE
   num number;
   fn number;

FUNCTION fx(x number)
RETURN number 
IS
   f number;
BEGIN
   IF x=0 THEN
      f := 1;
   ELSE
      f := x * fx(x-1);
   END IF;
RETURN f;
END;

BEGIN
   num:= 5;
   fn := fx(num);
   dbms_output.put_line(fn);
END;
```

Эта функция была на [PL/SQL quiz](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_online_quiz.htm). Правильный ответ там 125 хотя если я запускаю этот блок в Oracle то ответ 120. Я пытаюсь разобрать шаги которые отрабатываются в процедуре. Я не пойму как достигается эта цифра. Может кто-нибудь пожалуйста мне это объяснить?

Comment: В рамках обычной (земной) алгебры `5! = 120`. Как 125 может оказаться здесь верным ответом ???

Comment: @MaxU Что такое 5!?

Comment: @SovereignSun, ["5 факториал"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB)

Comment: @MaxU А как работает функция? просто я считаю и у меня не сходиться. 5=0 не верно, значит идёт в else а там, f=5*fx(4), а fx(4) это f=5*fx(3) и вообще не логично это всё.

Comment: *а fx(4) это f=5*fx(3)* нет, `fx(4)=4*fx(3)`. Ибо в этой копии процедуры своя переменная `x`, со своим переданным ей значением.

Comment: что-то вроде: `fx(5)` => `5*fx(4) => `5*4*fx(3)` => `5*4*3*fx(2)` => `5*4*3*2*fx(1)` = > `5*4*3*2*1`

Comment: Здесь не достигается 125 никакими способами. Ответ в тесте неверен. И такое бывает.

Answer (score 1):

Это функция [рекурсивного](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) вычисления [факториала](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial), но она работает только для положительных чисел, поэтому если вы поставите `num:= -5;` функция уйдет в бесконечный цикл

Comment: а где вы увидели `num:= -5;`? PS я ваш ответ не минусовал...

Comment: Я минусовал ответ, за английский. И я же и перевел.

Comment: @MaxU я не увидел -5 в вашем коде, я добавил от себя, что работает только для положительных, т.е. код написан не безопасно и при установке отрицательного - уйдет в бесконечный цикл

Comment: @Barmaley писал ответ на английском, т.к. думал что модератор перенесет на основной сайт, раньше так уже делали.

Comment: @SergeNazarenko, да, функция написана неудачно - но она в таком виде дана в опросе, поэтому автор вопроса ее поменять не может...

Comment: @SergeNazarenko не делайте больше так - минус снял :)